# disable automatic checks for compile errors on keystroke

Tags: android, android-studio

Now that my Android project is getting bigger,  every time I type a key, there's a 1-2 second delay until the character shows up on the screen. I know this is because Android studio is doing a bunch of smart stuff in background. I already disabled auto-pop code completion.

**EDIT:** problem only happens after Android Studio has been open for a few hours, and if I restart it, problem goes away.

One thing in particular I would like to disable is the checking for symbols. Every time I hit a key, it checks my entire project to see if that symbol exists. I'd like to defer this action to when I either save the file, compile, or am inactive for at least 5 seconds, but definitely not every time I hit a key.

Is there a way I can achieve this? Do you have any other tips for speeding things up?

I have an intel i7 with 12GB of DDR3 RAM. Only other programs I have running is music stream in Chrome and some more chrome tabs, and a large PDF file for my design.

Comment: In my experience this shouldn't be slow. Android Studio/IntelliJ do pretty smart indexing of your project so it's not like it has to recompile the world with every keystroke. When developing Android Studio (in IntelliJ), which has on the order of 3.5 million lines of code, I don't see typing delays at all, and AS shouldn't differ. Any chance you're editing extremely large files? That may be slow. Make sure you give Android Studio a big Java heap (Google for instructions on setting its heap size). Failing that, look for instructions on getting an IntelliJ thread dump and examine that for clues.

Comment: One thing I have seen is slowdowns if it needs to do a lot of background rescanning/reindexing of files if it's working in a huge codebase and it thinks files have changed. Do you see it reporting long-running background tasks in the window status area/background tasks view?

Comment: -My files are not that large. -I'm not sure what you mean by "the window status area" or "background task view", but if you tell me the exact name of the window, I will check. I also added new info, please read edits.

Comment: Window > Background Tasks > Show will get you there. If the problems only start to happen after Android Studio have been running a while and go away on restart, then it's likely a memory leak in Android Studio. Giving it more heap will ameliorate the problem, but the most helpful thing would be if you could get a Java heap dump and attach it to a bug submitted at b.android.com.